# Cheaper alternative to rogue fitness band?

Tags: mobility

I would like to get a (or some) band to do some mobility exercises, like those used often in mobilitywod.com.

The brand I regularly see cited is Rogue Fitness, but it seems very expensive.  Around $40 for one band, and I think it's basically just rubber.

Is there some cost to making these that I'm missing, or is there another brand that's a good option that I could get instead for less?

Comment: Have you looked on Amazon?

Comment: John has some input on this related question and answer: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/resistance-bands-what-do-the-resistance-ranges-of-x-to-y-pounds-mean?rq=1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it';s about a shopping recommendation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping recommendation.

Comment: I'm happy with bands from Evolutionize.   By the way, I disagree that this question is off topic.  You need the right equipment and props to exercise right, and where else can the OP get a question like this answered?   I spend a huge amount of time researching each piece of equipment before I buy.

Answer (score 1):

There's a brand called WODfitters which make those bands and other mobility related equipment. I got them from Amazon with the same intention as you, to use them with mobilitywod.com.

You should also be able to get a pair of lacrose balls stuck together (called the peanut) as an alternative to the gemini used on mobilitywod.com.

Answer (score 0):

As with most exercise equipment, the odds are good that you can get one for free via Freecycle, or cheap via Craigslist (slightly more dear via EBay). Exercise is hard, and many people are happy to get the symbol of their failure out of the house.

Outside of that, if you decide to make your own, it's basically just rubber. Inner tubes, especially ones from blown-out bicycle tires, are a cheap alternative. Surgical tubing is more reliable and precise. In either case, covering it with something like a cloth tube will help avoid having the strap cut into you. You can find tutorials online such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdV8Ajwbe5Y).